# application specific database file - visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, database

I am trying to create a small C# application in VS2010. I need to add a database file to the project such that the file is present at any computer that I install the application on. Is that possible? If yes, what kind of database file can I add to my project? also how do I make sure that the database file will be available in the installation package ?
please help.thanks.

Comment: you could use Ms-Access as Databse so you can easily deploy it in client pc.

Comment: Maybe [SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11591002/1541819) is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Did you look at Compact Edition?  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172037.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to add a database file to the project such that the file is
>   present at any computer that I install the application on. Is that
>   possible?

**Yes** it is possible, you can use `MS-Access` as `Database` so that it can be deployed on client PC easily.

**Steps on how to use MS-Access in your project:**

**1.**  Open `MS-Access` and create a `Database`.
**2.**  create `Tables` as per your requirement.
**3.**  now save the database file with `.accdb` extension in your project `Debug/Release` folder (it really depends on from wherever you want to `execute` your program).
**4.**  now write your program to perform `DB operations` on that file.

Sample Code:
I have given you sample code here on how to execute `insert into` command.

->i have created `CollegeDB.accdb` access file and kept inside `Release` folder.
->`CollegeDB.accdb` file contains Table `Student` with following `3` columns

**ID     Name     Address**

```
       private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=CollegeDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;");
            OleDbCommand command=new OleDbCommand("insert into student values(@id,@name,@address)",con);
            con.Open();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 503);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "kumar");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", "andhra");
            if(command.ExecuteNonQuery()>0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Row Inserted Succesfully!");
            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

same way you can perform other operations aswell.